# How to check if relativedelta object is negative

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I have some problem with using relativedelta objects - cannot determine if "delta is negative". What I'm trying is:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
print relativedelta(seconds=-5) > 0
```

that gives me `True` which is counter intuitive.

```
print relativedelta(seconds=5) > 0
```

also return `True`. Is there a way to check if "delta" represented by relativedata object is negative?

I'm currently using a workaround in the form of separate function to check if delta is negative but I expected that there is more elegant solution. Here is code I'm using:

```
def is_relativedelta_positive(rel_delta):
    is_positive = True
    is_positive &= rel_delta.microseconds >= 0
    is_positive &= rel_delta.seconds >= 0
    is_positive &= rel_delta.minutes >= 0
    is_positive &= rel_delta.hours >= 0
    is_positive &= rel_delta.days >= 0 
    return is_positive
```

Comment: This approach with testing if all components are not negative doesn't work since it is possible to have mixed positive and negative values e.g.  relativedelta(seconds+5, microseconds=-12345).

Comment: Using `&=` is quite obscure even if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`relativedelta()` objects do not implement the necessary comparison methods. In Python 2 that means that they are thus compared *by their type name*, and numbers are always sorted before any other objects; this makes these objects larger than integer values whatever their values. In Python 3 you'd get a `TypeError` instead.

Your work-around doesn't account for an absolute positive value, `relativedelta(years=1, seconds=-5)` would move your datetime by *almost* a whole year *forward*, so it could hardly be named a negative delta.

You'd have to compare individual attributes instead (so `years`, `months`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` and `microseconds`). Depending on your use-case, you may have to convert those to a total number of seconds:

```
def total_seconds(rd, _yeardays=365.2425, _monthdays=365.2425/12):
    """approximation of the number of seconds in a relative delta"""
    # year and month durations are averages, taking into account leap years
    total_days = rd.years * _yeardays + (rd.months * _monthdays) + rd.days
    total_hours = total_days * 24 + rd.hours
    total_minutes = total_hours * 60 + rd.minutes
    return total_minutes * 60 + rd.seconds + (rd.microseconds / 1000000)
```

then use this to do your comparisons:

```
if total_seconds(relativedelta(seconds=-5)) > 0:
```

The `total_seconds()` function produces an *approximation*; relative deltas handle leap years and the right number of days per month, so their actual effect on a datetime object will vary depending on that datetime value. However, the above should be good enough for the majority of cases. It does completely ignore the *absolute* components of the relative delta (`hour`, `year`, the singular names, that state a fixed value rather than a delta).

Comment: Thank you @martijn-pieters for the answer - seems that approach with approximation of number of seconds works best for me. One minor correction in`total_seconds()` function you provided - microseconds should be divided by 10^6 not 10^3.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There's no need to call `rd.normalized()` there. The rest of the math works out just fine if you're working with floats as if you're working with integers.

Comment: @Paul: ah, yes, I made an assumption about normalization converting weeks and other group values. But looking at the implementation I see I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** There is not a clear and intuitive definition of comparison between `relativedelta` objects, so comparison is not implemented in `dateutil`. If you want to compare them, you'll need to make an arbitrary choice about the ordering.

### The problem

The semantics of comparisons between `relativedelta` are undefined because `relativedelta` objects themselves don't represent a fixed period of time. You can see [this issue on github](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/350) as to why this is a problem.

There are two major problems with comparisons between `relativedelta` objeccts. The more straightforward one is that `relativedelta` has "absolute" components (the singular arguments) such as `day`, `hour`, etc. So consider:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

rd1 = relativedelta(day=5, hours=5)
rd2 = relativedelta(hours=8)

for i in range(4, 7):
    dt = datetime(2014, 1, i)
    print((dt + rd1) > (dt + rd2))

# Result:
# True
# False
# False
```

Since each `relativedelta` does not represent a fixed amount of time, it's not necessarily meaningful to compare which one is "bigger" or "smaller" than the other.

The other problem is that even if you restrict yourself to the "relative" components of the `relativedelta`, all units larger than `week` depend on what they are being added to, so:

```
rd3 = relativedelta(months=1)
rd4 = relativedelta(days=30)

for i in range(1, 4):
    dt = datetime(2015, i, 1)
    print((dt + rd3) > (dt + rd4))

# Result:
# True
# False
# True
```

### Possible comparison operations

That said, there are a few possible definitions that you can meaningfully use if you want a semi-arbitrary but consistent definition of "less than" for `relativedelta`.

One somewhat limited version of this is to say that "absolute" components will throw an error and to set a fixed value for the "relative" components:

```
def rd_to_td(rd):
    for comp in ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second',
                 'microsecond', 'weekday', 'leapdays']:
        if getattr(rd, comp) is not None:
            raise ValueError('Conversion not supported with component ' + comp)

    YEAR_LEN = 365.25
    MON_LEN = 30

    days = (rd.years or 0) * YEAR_LEN
    days += (rd.months or 0) * MON_LEN
    return timedelta(days=days, hours=rd.hours, minutes=rd.minutes,
                     seconds=rd.seconds, microseconds=rd.microseconds)
```

### Closest to universal comparison

The above works for limited cases, but probably most universal comparison method you can define is to simply add both to a fixed date and compare the results:

```
from datetime import datetime

def lt_at_dt(rd1, rd2, dt=datetime(1970, 1, 1)):
    return (dt + rd1) < (dt + rd2)
```

If you want this as a key for sorting (rather than for pairwise comparisons), this same definition of "less than" can be used to convert `relativedelta` to `timedelta` (which is a fixed period of time):

```
def rd_to_td_at_dt(rd, dt=datetime(1970, 1, 1)):
    return (dt + rd1) - dt
```

**Note** The previous two definitions are about the more general operation of *comparison* between `relativedelta` objects. To know if one of these is *negative*, just compare the result to a relativedelta representing zero, or convert to `timedelta` by one of the above methods and compare to `timedelta(0)`.

Finally, I will note that in the forthcoming 2.7.0 release of `dateutil`, `relativedelta` will define `__abs__` ([GH PR #472](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/pull/472/files)), so your original definition of positivity can be reduced to `abs(rd) == rd`. However, as Martijn points out, `abs(relativedelta(days=20, hours=-1)) != relativedelta(days=20, hours=-1)`, but by most reasonable definitions, that relative delta is always a positive offset.

Comment: Thank you @Paul for wide explanation - examples from github were very informative.

Comment: It's your choice which answer to select, but I think the other answer is somewhat less accurate in that it treats `relativedelta` as if it could only be used as a "calendardelta", without dealing with the fact that it also acts as a ["partial datetime"](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/449).

Answer (score 2):

An elegant and concise way of checking whether a relativedelta object is negative:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def is_negative(rd: relativedelta) -> bool:
''' Check whether a relativedelta object is negative'''
    try:
        datetime.min + rd
        return False
    except OverflowError:
        return True
```

Some examples:

```
is_negative(relativedelta(hours=1))
>> False
is_negative(relativedelta(hours=0))
>> False
is_negative(relativedelta(hours=-1))
>> True
is_negative(relativedelta(days=1, hours=-1))
>> False
is_negative(relativedelta(days=-1, hours=1))
>> True
```